# One monitor crashes to a solid green screen

Tags: windows-7

Recently my left monitor has been displaying a solid green color randomly, or after turning off and then back on. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Both my monitors are by Dell, not sure of the model of the one having the problem. The graphics card is an MSI R9 290 4GB. The left monitor is connected via HDMI cable and the right via DVI.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I simply had to remove the cable from my graphics card and plug it back in, it then worked and went back to the normal dual-monitor setup it was.

(I was going to ask this question, but then I found out how to fix it so I'm going to answer it so other people know how to solve the same problem.)